# Arduino-compatible micro-controller with both I2C and CAN

Tags: i2c, can-bus

I am looking for a controller that works with Arduino (i.e. there is official or third-party support for the controller in the Arduino IDE and core libs) and has both built-in CAN and I2C buses. I was looking at the ATMega automotive series (16M1, 32M1, 64M1, 32C1, 64C1) but it does not mention I2C/TWI in the datasheet at all.

(I know I can bitbang I2C, I know there is MCP2515 for CAN over SPI.)

Thanks!

**EDIT:** The application in mind is a bridge between a few I2C sensors and CAN, no complex logic. High performance is not necessary, plus it will drive costs upwards.

Comment: the ESP32 comes to mind. you can disable wifi/bt to save power and make it more like a mega

Comment: Thanks, @dandavis, ESP32 is too much :) I added a note on looking for rather low-performance chips.

Comment: Is i2c to CAN conversion possible on microcontroller which has both CAN and I2C.(TM4C123GXL)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many options come to mind:

- Bluepill board
- Literally any board with I2C and CAN buses from the STM32 series, as searchable on their website (https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/microcontrollers.html)
- ESP32

A Bluebill board is programmable with mbed, STM32HAL (CubeMX) and Arduino, all of which have either CAN libraries for the CAN peripheral or have it even built-in in the OS (mbedos).

The Bluepill board is extremely low cost ($1.81 with free shipping from aliexpress) and features an STM32F103C8 microcontroller with 128kB Flash and 20kB RAM. Its peripherals include two I2C and one CAN bus.

[image]

[image]

Infos & Datasheet: http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f103c8.html, http://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Blue_Pill

For flashing and debugging the chip you should have one cheap ST-Linkv2 clone (~3$ from china).

For programming environments you can use:

- Arduino IDE (STM32Duino Arduino Core for STM32F1/F3/F4 chips: http://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Boards_Manager_package)
- PlatformIO, more general purpose and more powerful (https://platformio.org:443/boards?count=15&filter%5Bmcu%5D=STM32F103C&page=1&sorting%5Bname%5D=asc)

As frameworks you can use:

- Arduino (see above)
- ARM mbedos (builds upon STM32HAL, natively supported by PlatformIO)
- STM32HAL (e.g. with project files for an IDE generated by STM32CubeMX)

Documentation references:

- https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.8/reference/can.html
- https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00154093.pdf (Chapter 8)
- https://github.com/Locoduino/Commanders

8 Bit microcontrollers from STM8AF series have a few micros with 1 I2C and 1 CAN bus: See http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm8af-series.html?querycriteria=productId=SS1583

[image]

Ready buyable evaluation board: http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm8a-discovery.html (you want the STM8AF5288 one)

The toolchain changes then, of course. See https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/extended-query.html?querycriteria=productId=LN1759$$associatedTo=SS1584

Comment: Good answer. Anything 8bit, though?

Comment: @eudoxos sure, updated.